# Serving Static TXT Files from Phoenix

Tags: routes, elixir, assets, phoenix-framework

I need to serve a Static TXT file from my Phoenix app, for domain verification purposes:

• Google Search Console

• GoGetSSL certification

Both companies asked me to upload, each a different TXT file that would be verified on the root path of my domain.

Like so: **http://example.com/091823091231902322389.txt**

I downloaded the TXT file and have placed it into the `web/static/assets` folder.

But when trying to reach it using the browser I obviously get a `no route found for GET`

How can I make sure files within the `web/static/assets` folder are served by Phoenix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding the file to `web/static/assets`, you also need to add the filename to the `Plug.Static` whitelist. In your `lib/my_app/endpoint.ex`, change:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

to

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt 091823091231902322389.txt)
```